# how to compute conv2d C++ code is in tensorflow?

Tags: c++, tensorflow

I am just starting a study about tensorflow. As I google, the tensorflow functions are just a Python functions for building a tensorFlow graph, And the real computation part is composed by C++ code. But I can't find the multiplication part of that C++ code..TT I want to know that how to be computed the 'conv2d' function is in practice.

Comment: In general it is a good idea to post some code examples to show what you have done so far. This will help people to provide a good answer to your question.

Comment: Also there is no such thing as C/C++ - they are two separate languages with some similarities

Comment: thank you for your comments :)

Comment: And tensorflow is open source, so you can find the entire source code online (here: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow). e.g.: this seems to be the source file you are looking for: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/kernels/conv_2d.h